# export excel with a query using maatwebsite with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Hello i'm really new using maatwebsite already read the documentation but cant find it, can someone give me an idea about executing query after exporting excel using maatwebsite? here is my code :

```
public function export()
{
    Excel::download(new KodePosExport, 'KodePos.xlsx');
    KodePos::query()->truncate();
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
}
```

it's able redirect to the page that i wanted and truncate the data but not exporting the excel, how can i do it? Thank you

If using this function exporting excel working perfectly, but not query included

```
public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new KodePosExport, 'KodePos.xlsx');
    //KodePos::query()->truncate();
    // return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
}
```

Comment: which kind of query?... post what you have tried so far (or a pseudo code to understand  what you want)

Comment: @Berto99 sorry i'm edit my question up there...can you help me?

Comment: exporting the excel where?

Comment: @lagbox with this working perfectly to export the excel but not query included = return Excel::download(new KodePosExport, 'KodePos.xlsx');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$download = Export::download(...);

KodePos::query()->truncate();

return $download;
```

Comment: and how to change the page after exporting the file? i want to using something like this return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');

Comment: you don't ... `Export::download` makes a download response (which is the complete response for this request) you can't then send another response after that

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest two solutions here;

- [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#terminable-middleware)

> Sometimes a middleware may need to do some work after the HTTP response has been sent to the browser. If you define a terminate method on your middleware and your web server is using FastCGI, the terminate method will automatically be called after the response is sent to the browser.

- Creating an async job and trigger it with delay before the download process(your queue driver shouldn't be `sync`, `redis` is a great candidate)

```
class KudeposTruncater extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    
    public function handle()
    {
        KodePos::query()->truncate();
    }
}
```

```
\Queue::later(15, new KudeposTruncater());

return Excel::download(new KodePosExport, 'KodePos.xlsx');
```